# Como agregar a un array resultado de firestore en firebase y js

Tags: javascript, array, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

tengo una función  que me trae los documentos de una base de datos de firestore.

lo que me gustaría es que esos documentos los pueda meter a un array para asi poder jugar con ellos, pero no me funciona, intento aprovechar el forEach para eso.

```
function sort() {

  db.collection("colores").where("color", "==", "azules")
  .get()
  .then(function(querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
       
         array = doc.data().color;
          
      });
     
  })

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que aparece algún ejemplo en la documentación oficial. Sería algo así:

```js
let data = [];
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  data.push({id: doc.id, ...doc.data()});
});
// Aquí ya puedes operar con `data`. Yo, por ejemplo, hago esto:
data = data.sort((a, b) => a.orden - b.orden)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias el ejemplo muy claro, sirvió mucho.